# Adding Zeromq to an existing Java Gradle project from Github

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, zeromq

I have downloaded a Java Gradle project from Github. I'm using Eclipse.
Now I want to incorporate ZeroQM to the project using Jeromq.
https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq

What steps must I follow in Eclipse so I can write
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZContext;

and create a Zmq client inside an existing class in the current gradle environment

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use gradle there is no need to download anything.
Just open the file build.gradle that you should already have and add

```
compile group: 'org.zeromq', name: 'jeromq', version: '0.5.2'
```

inside the 'dependencies' section.
At least this is how IntelliJ Idea works, but Eclipse should be more or less the same.

Hope this helps.